# Call templates with same match string in different context

Tags: xslt

I want to transform a source xml into a target xml where certain matches from the source xml are included in different context in the target xml. For example I have a source xml like:

```
<shiporder>
  <shipto>orderperson1</shipto>
  <shipto>orderperson1</shipto>
  <city>London</city>
</shiporder>
```

On this source xml I apply the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="root" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/shiporder"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="Customer"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="Customer">
    <Customer>
        <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="/shiporder"/>-->
    </Customer>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="shipto"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipto">
    <Address>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </Address>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the template of name Customer I like to apply a template like:

```
 <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="city"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/shiporder/city">
    <City>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </City>
 </xsl:template>
```

But I already defined a template with match `/shiporder`. So I don't know how to design a stylesheet where both templates with the same match exists in their own context?

Comment: Use `mode` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#modes

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. 1) `/shiporder` can never really match anything, because apparently your document starts at `/root`. Please use working code for examples. Even if it does not produce the right results - it should not contain mistakes like that. 2) You did not say what output you expect. Please include an output that matches the input sample.

Comment: @Tomalak I dont understand your complaining under point 1) please see the working example [here](http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuL/3)

Answer (score 1):

If you use mode, like @michael.hor257k suggested you can differentiate between two or more templates that match on the same element but with different results.

In your case that could end up looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="root" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/shiporder" mode="root"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="Customer"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="Customer">
    <Customer>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/shiporder" mode="customer"/>
    </Customer>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/shiporder" mode="root">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="shipto"/>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/shiporder" mode="customer">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="city"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="shipto">
    <Address>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </Address>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="city">
    <City>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </City>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously all credits here go to Michael for pointing this out first.

Comment: Thx, I got the hint that Michael suggested. Are there more solutions or only the "mode" one? In the example case one mode would be enough " _if an xsl:apply-templates element does not have a mode attribute, then it applies only to those template rules from xsl:template elements that do not have a mode attribute_ "